# Maximizing the Leontief inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, inverse, nonlinear-optimization

Let $X$ be the set of $n$ by $n$ matrices with elements $0\leq x_{ij}\leq 1$ for all $(i,j)$ and   such that $\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} \leq \bar{x}$ for all $i$ and where $\bar{x}$ is some number such that $0<\bar{x}<1$.

Define the Leontief inverse as $L(x)=(I-x)^{-1}$, note that given the restrictions on $X$ the matrix $(I-x)$ is invertible for all $x\in X$. I am interested in the following maximization problem
$$
\max_{x\in X} \alpha^TL(x)\,\beta
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are column vectors.

I can take the first-order conditions of this problem but I don't know if they are sufficient. So a solution to the first-order conditions is no guarantee of optimality.

My questions are:

1. Is there a clever way to solve this problem?
2. Can we show that first-order conditions are sufficient?
3. Is there a reference that would tackle these types of problems?

Many thanks!